# Parsing broken RSS feeds with Perl

Tags: xml, perl, rss, atom-feed

I would like to be able to parse RSS and Atom feeds that contain
non-valid XML. The errors I have encountered and would like to fix
include "simple" things such as a `&gt` where the closing `;` is
missing, missing closing tags and closing tags that appear in the
wrong order.

I would like to ignore the question whether in theory it makes any
sense to attempt parsing malformed XML documents at all. One
"technical" term that seems to come rather close to what I want to do
is "tag soup". What existing CPAN modules should I use to build such a
parser that is able to tolerate or correct simple errors like those
described above?

Answer (score 4):

The `recover` flag to [LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML::Parser#finish_push), if you really must, or [XML-Liberal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Liberal) if you really want to go overboard in parsing any old rubbish.

I'm sure you would like to ignore the question of whether parsing non-well-formed documents makes any sense, but ignoring it won't make it go away. Most RSS tools will correctly reject any non-well-formed XML input completely; you should generally follow suit, unless your tool is something unusual like an RSS debugger.

“Tag soup” is a term specifically related to HTML parsing. One of the central ideas of XML (and hence RSS and Atom) is that there is no such thing.